# Problema com carregamento de dados de bd local para dois pickers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Ola. Tenho dois pickers que carrega dados de uma api. Um picker traz dados de categorias e o outro subcategoria. Quando seleciono uma categoria o picker subcategoria e carregado com os dados da subcategoria correspondente. Salvo esses dados selecionados em um bd local. Até ai tudo bem.

O problema ocorre quando eu carrego os dados do bd local para os pickers para fazer a edição do cadastro. O picker de categoria traz o dado sem problema, mas o picker sub categoria as vezes traz o dado e as vezes não.

```
private async void VerificaClassificadoBaseLocal()
    {
        if (DataBase.GetClassificado() != null)
        {
            ActIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            ActIndicator.IsRunning = true;

            try
            {
                var dadosSituacao = await SituacaoClassificadoService.VerificaSituacaoClassificado(DataBase.GetAppKey());

                LblSituacao.Text = dadosSituacao.situacao;
                LblObservacao.Text = dadosSituacao.obs;

                var dadosClassificadoLocal = DataBase.GetClassificado();

                List<Categoria> ListaCategorias = await CategoriaService.GetCategoria(DataBase.GetAppKey());
                var _categoria = ListaCategorias.FindIndex(c => c.categoria == dadosClassificadoLocal.categ);
                PckCategoria.SelectedIndex = _categoria;

                var objCategoria = (Categoria)PckCategoria.SelectedItem;
                List<SubCategoria> ListaSubCategorias = await SubCategoriaService.GetSubCategoria(DataBase.GetAppKey(), objCategoria.idcategoria);
                var _subCategoria = ListaSubCategorias.FindIndex(s => s.subcategoria == dadosClassificadoLocal.subcateg);
                PckSubCategoria.SelectedIndex = _subCategoria;

                List<Hora> ListaHoras = Horarios.GetHoras();
                var Hora1Inicial = ListaHoras.FindIndex(h => h.Horas == dadosClassificadoLocal.contato_h1.Substring(0, 5));
                PckHora1Inicial.SelectedIndex = Hora1Inicial;

                var Hora1Final = ListaHoras.FindIndex(h => h.Horas == dadosClassificadoLocal.contato_h1.Substring(5, 5));
                PckHora1Final.SelectedIndex = Hora1Final;

                var Hora2Inicial = ListaHoras.FindIndex(h => h.Horas == dadosClassificadoLocal.contato_h2.Substring(0, 5));
                PckHora2Inicial.SelectedIndex = Hora2Inicial;

                var Hora2Final = ListaHoras.FindIndex(h => h.Horas == dadosClassificadoLocal.contato_h2.Substring(5, 5));
                PckHora2Final.SelectedIndex = Hora2Final;

                TxtTitulo.Text = dadosClassificadoLocal.titulo;
                TxtTexto.Text = dadosClassificadoLocal.texto;
                TxtTelefone.Text = dadosClassificadoLocal.contato_tel;
                TxtEmail.Text = dadosClassificadoLocal.contato_email;

            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Erro => " + erro, "Ok");
            }

            ActIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            ActIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Os outros pickers depois da subcategoria carregam os dados selecionados sempre? Sim.  Esse "as vezes traz o dado e as vezes não" é aleatório mesmo? Sim, se eu tentar 5 vezes ele carregar as 5 vezes e pode não carregar as 5.

Comment: Ok. Tem bindings envolvidos nessa história toda? Tentou substituir o uso do `objCategoria` por `ListaCategorias[_categoria]`?

Comment: Eu tô achando que deve haver alguma operação fora de sincronia entre o momento em que você seta o `SelectedIndex` e o componente (picker de categoria) infere o `SelectedItem`, e algumas vezes esse `objCategoria` que você tenta pegar para descobrir a subcategoria pode estar vindo nulo. Tenta dar um alert quando ele retornar nulo ou quando `_subCategoria ` retornar um índice inválido...

Comment: Me expressei mal acima. O picker subcategoria quando eu carrego os dados do bd local ele carrega as subcategorias, porém o que acontece é que ele não mostra ("não da display") no picker da subcategoria que esta salva no bd. Por exemplo: O picker categoria carrega as categorias da api  e mostra na tela a categoria salva no bd,ex. Animais; O picker subcategoria carrega as subcategorias da api e tem que mostrar a subcategoria salva no bd local, no caso, teria que mostrar Cachorros. Só que isso as vezes não ocorre. Já verifiquei antes e os dados são trazidos da api, mas vou tentar o q vc falou.